# VC++6 error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

Made this simple class with MSVC++ 6.0

```
class Strg
{
public:
    Strg(int max);
private:
    int _max;
};


Strg::Strg(int max)
{
  _max=max;
}
```

Sounds good if I use it in :

```
main()
{
  Strg mvar(10);
}
```

But Now If I use it in an another class :

```
class ok
{
public:
    Strg v(45);
};
```

I get message error : 
**error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'**

Could you tell me more please ?

Comment: -1 The anwser for your exact problem was really easy to google out: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/120826-syntax-error-constant.html

Comment: I'd upgrade your compiler too, VC6 is a relic...

Answer (score 7):

Should be:

```
class ok
{
public:
    Strg v;
    ok() : v(45) {}
};
```

Non-static member variables that don't have default constructors (v in this case) should be initialized using [initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). In functions (like main) on the other hand you can use the regular constructor syntax.

Answer (score 4):

What the compiler is complaining about is that you are trying to provide instruction on how ton instantiate the class member `v` inside your class definition, which is not allowed.

The place to instantiate `v` would be inside the contructor, or in the constructor's initializer list. For example:

Inside constructor:

```
class ok
{
public:
    Strg v;
    ok() {
        v = Strg(45);
    }
};
```

In initializer list:

```
class ok
{
public:
    Strg v;
    ok() : v(45) {}
};
```

The correct way to do it is the last one (otherwise, `v` would also require a default constructor and would be initialized twice).