# C2059: syntax error: constant

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am having trouble resolving a C:2059 error on lines 19-23.  I am certain my creation of a vector data type is correct.   Where have I gone wrong?

Debugger Output:
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Neutropenia_Application\classifier.h:21: error: C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

```
#ifndef CLASSIFIER_H
#define CLASSIFIER_H

#include "patient_data.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Classifier : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Classifier(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Classifier();
    void classify(std::vector<patient_data>data, patient_data i);

    struct CreateSDTable
    {
        std::vector<long> sum(3);    // C2509 error    //element 0 = Tumor, element 1 = Stage, element 2 = Adjuvant
        std::vector<long> mean(3);     // C2509 error
        std::vector<long> error(3);  // C2509 error
        std::vector<long> SDL(3);   // C2509 error
        std::vector<long> SD(3);  // C2509 error
    };

    CreateSDTable CurrentvsNeutropenic;
    CreateSDTable CurrentvsNonNeutropenic;

private:
/*
    std::vector<int> calculatesums(std::vector<patient_data> data, patient_data i);
    std::vector<long> calculatemean(std::vector<int>validpatients, CreateSDTable Neut, CreateSDTable NonNeut);
    std::vector<long>calculateerror(patient_data d, std::vector<int>m);
    std::vector<long>calculatSDL(int nvp, CreateSDTable CVN, CreateSDTable CVsNN);
    std::vector<int> NumofValidPatients(std::vector<patient_data>x);

    //void classify(std::vector<patient_data>data, patient_data i);
*/
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // CLASSIFIER_H
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VC++6 error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519035/vc6-error-c2059-syntax-error-constant)

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize member variables that way.  You need to separate declaration and initialization:

```
struct CreateSDTable {
    std::vector<int> sum;
    ...
    CreateSDTable() : sum(3), ... {}
};
```

Comment: You *can* in c++11 with a small tweak `std::vector<long> sum = std::vector<long>(3);`

Comment: another way in C++11 is `std::vector<long> sum { 0, 0, 0 };`  (the numbers are initial values for each member and the length of the list gives the size of the vector)